# Partially ordered permutations

Tags: permutations, combinations

If I have a set $X$ of length five such that $X=\{1,2,3,4,5\}.$ I want to find the number of permutations where the relative order of the $2$ sets $\{2,4\}$ and $\{2,5\}$ is maintained. In other words, $2$ always comes before $4$ and $5$ without any order restriction between $4$ and $5$. How do I represent it mathematically?

Comment: "If i have a matrix X of length five such that X={1,2,3,4,5}". So is $X$ a matrix or is it a set?!

Comment: set yes. my bad

Answer (score 2):

Pick three slots for $2, 4, 5$.

Put $2$ in the first of the three slots.

Arrange $4$ and $5$ in the other two chosen slots.

Arrange $1$ and $3$ in the remaining two slots.

Comment: I want an equation to get the final number

Comment: Try to work that out from the outline I gave in my answer.

Comment: Alternatively, take the number of ways to arrange $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, divide by the ways to arrange $\{2,4,5\}$, and then multiply by the ways to arrange $\{4,5\}$.